# why I have issues in importing views in the urls.py file?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

`from employee import views` 
does not work!...the server is giving a page not found (404) response 
here is the project structure:

```
employee
  migrations folder
....other files
   views.py
hrdjango
 __init__.py
 settings.py
 urls.py
```

I feel like the urls can't access my views 
this is the views.py

```
from .models import Employee  
# Create your views here.  
def emp(request):  
    if request.method == "POST":  
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            try:  
                form.save()  
                return redirect('/show')  
            except:  
                pass  
    else:  
        form = EmployeeForm()  
    return render(request,'index.html',{'form':form})  
def show(request):  
    employees = Employee.objects.all()  
    return render(request,"show.html",{'employees':employees})  
def edit(request, id):  
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)  
    return render(request,'edit.html', {'employee':employee})  
def update(request, id):  
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)  
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST, instance = employee)  
    if form.is_valid():  
        form.save()  
        return redirect("/show")
```

```
from django.contrib import admin  
from django.urls import path  
from employee import views  
urlpatterns = [  
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),  
    path('emp', views.emp),  
    path('show',views.show),  
    path('edit/<int:id>', views.edit),  
    path('update/<int:id>', views.update),  
    path('delete/<int:id>', views.destroy),  
]
```

urls.py

I am having unresolved import 'employee'message

Answer (score 1):

Is this the project urls.py or the app-level urls.py? If this is your app level urls.py, then the import should be `from . import views`. If it is the project-level urls.py, then post up your file structure so we can see if the import structure is wrong.

Comment: it is the project level urls.py, the project structure is there I dont have the urls.py in my app (employee)

Answer (score 1):

I think the better solution would be to use separate urls.py file for separate apps and then include them to your root urls.

create a urls.py in your app.

in your root urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
   ...,
   ...,
   path('employee/', include('employee.urls')),
]
```